# Page not showing the same in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, font-face

Can anyone explain to me why the font in the menu (i.e. Accessories, Children, Mens, Womens) here http://www.urlgone.com/f9d64e/ is not showing correctly in IE8. In IE8 its using Arial but in all other browsers I checked its using the @font-face font expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `@font-face` support is slightly different across different browsers. In particular, IE supports only embedded open-type fonts (EOT), and therefore a [font-reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#src-desc) for this needs to be included if you are going to see your font rendered correctly in IE. There is a good, universal syntax for `@font-face` rules [available here](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax).

Comment: Not sure why you are saying this. IE has supported @font-face since at least version 5. They just require their own format, the EOT.

Comment: Thanks. I had taken the site I referenced at face value. You are quite correct, I've edited the answer accordingly.